# Smart contract has stopped working well (runs out of gas)

Tags: solidity, erc-20, gas-limit, out-of-gas, debugging

I created an ERC20-compliant token with a tax and redistribution mechanism and deployed to the Bitgert  chain and it has worked fine for days now. It stopped working well yesterday and efforts to debug have proved almost successful albeit I have not been able to surmount the problem. I used the debug API (I run a node for the network and exposed the debug API) and I keep seeing the error "out of gas" which should be easy to fix right (I just need to increase gas limit)? The problem is I haven't been able to find the exact gas limit that makes the transaction work. I have overridden the internal `_transfer` function of the ERC20 contract from Openzeppelin to implement this taxing and redistribution. Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "./helpers/TransferHelpers.sol";

contract VefiEcosystemTokenV2 is Ownable, AccessControl, ERC20 {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  address public taxCollector;
  address[] public liquidityPools;
  address[] public holders;

  bytes32 public taxExclusionPrivilege = keccak256(abi.encode("TAX_EXCLUSION_PRIVILEGE"));

  uint8 public taxPercentage;

  constructor(
    string memory name_,
    string memory symbol_,
    uint256 amount,
    address _taxCollector,
    uint8 _taxPercentage
  ) ERC20(name_, symbol_) {
    taxCollector = _taxCollector;
    taxPercentage = _taxPercentage;
    _mint(_msgSender(), amount);
    _grantRole(taxExclusionPrivilege, _msgSender());
    holders.push(_msgSender());
  }

  function _indexOfList(address[] memory list, address item) internal pure returns (uint256 index) {
    index = uint256(int256(-1));

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i] == item) {
        index = i;
      }
    }
  }

  function _afterTokenTransfer(
    address,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
  ) internal virtual override(ERC20) {
    if (amount > 0) {
      if (_indexOfList(holders, to) == uint256(int256(-1)) && _indexOfList(liquidityPools, to) == uint256(int256(-1))) {
        holders.push(to);
      }
    }
  }

  function _splitFeesFromTransfer(uint256 amount)
    internal
    view
    returns (
      uint256 forHolders,
      uint256 forPools,
      uint256 forTaxCollector
    )
  {
    uint256 totalTaxValue = amount.mul(uint256(taxPercentage)).div(100);
    forHolders = totalTaxValue.div(3);
    forPools = totalTaxValue.div(3);
    forTaxCollector = totalTaxValue.div(3);
  }

  function _transfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
  ) internal virtual override(ERC20) {
    if (!hasRole(taxExclusionPrivilege, from) && from != address(this)) {
      (uint256 forHolders, uint256 forPools, uint256 forTaxCollector) = _splitFeesFromTransfer(amount);
      uint256 paymentToTaxCollector = forTaxCollector;
      // gas savings
      address[] memory internalHolders = holders;
      address[] memory holdersWithSufficientBalance = new address[](internalHolders.length);

      for (uint256 i = 0; i < internalHolders.length; i++) {
        if (balanceOf(internalHolders[i]) > 0) {
          holdersWithSufficientBalance[i] = internalHolders[i];
        }
      }

      uint256 countOfZeroAddressesHolders;

      for (uint256 i = 0; i < holdersWithSufficientBalance.length; i++) {
        if (holdersWithSufficientBalance[i] == address(0)) {
          countOfZeroAddressesHolders = countOfZeroAddressesHolders.add(1);
        }
      }

      uint256 amountPerHolders = forHolders.div(holdersWithSufficientBalance.length.sub(countOfZeroAddressesHolders));

      for (uint256 i = 0; i < holdersWithSufficientBalance.length; i++) {
        if (holdersWithSufficientBalance[i] != address(0)) {
          super._transfer(from, holdersWithSufficientBalance[i], amountPerHolders);
        }
      }

      //gas savings
      address[] memory internalLPs = liquidityPools;

      uint256 countOfZeroAddressesLPs;

      for (uint256 i = 0; i < internalLPs.length; i++) {
        if (internalLPs[i] == address(0)) {
          countOfZeroAddressesLPs = countOfZeroAddressesLPs.add(1);
        }
      }

      if (internalLPs.length > 0) {
        uint256 amountPerLPs = forPools.div(internalLPs.length.sub(countOfZeroAddressesLPs));

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < internalLPs.length; i++) {
          if (internalLPs[i] != address(0)) {
            super._transfer(from, internalLPs[i], amountPerLPs);
          }
        }
      } else {
        paymentToTaxCollector = paymentToTaxCollector.add(forPools);
      }

      super._transfer(from, taxCollector, paymentToTaxCollector);
      super._transfer(from, to, amount.sub(forHolders + forPools + forTaxCollector));
    } else {
      super._transfer(from, to, amount);
    }
  }

  function setTaxPercentage(uint8 _taxPercentage) external onlyOwner {
    taxPercentage = _taxPercentage;
  }

  function setTaxCollector(address _taxCollector) external onlyOwner {
    taxCollector = _taxCollector;
  }

  function excludeFromPayingTax(address account) external onlyOwner {
    require(!hasRole(taxExclusionPrivilege, account), "already_excluded_from_paying_tax");
    _grantRole(taxExclusionPrivilege, account);
  }

  function includeInTaxPayment(address account) external onlyOwner {
    require(hasRole(taxExclusionPrivilege, account), "already_pays_tax");
    _revokeRole(taxExclusionPrivilege, account);
  }

  function addLiquidityPool(address lp) external onlyOwner {
    uint256 index = _indexOfList(liquidityPools, lp);
    require(index == uint256(int256(-1)), "lp_already_in_list");
    liquidityPools.push(lp);
  }

  function removeLiquidityPool(address lp) external onlyOwner {
    uint256 index = _indexOfList(liquidityPools, lp);
    require(index > uint256(int256(-1)), "lp_not_in_list");
    address[] storage lps = liquidityPools;
    delete lps[index];
  }

  function retrieveEther(address to) external onlyOwner {
    TransferHelpers._safeTransferEther(to, address(this).balance);
  }

  function retrieveERC20(
    address token,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
  ) external onlyOwner {
    TransferHelpers._safeTransferERC20(token, to, amount);
  }
}
```

The code with sources can be found here: https://brisescan.com/address/0xA0beD207C2449e84dc56128B22FdB077C1930495/contracts

Comment: What was the answer to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possibilities here, but it will be tricky to figure it out without more data.

- 1. The account calling the smart contract function simply doesn't have enough `ETH` to pay for the transaction
- 2. The complexity/price of one of your functions has grown so immense that its `gas cost` is above `blockGasLimit`. (This might be possible because you are using a lot of loops in your code). Do check how much time your function call is supposed to loop through based on the number of holders etc.

Comment: Your second point is it. I figured that the array's length had increased drastically. I'm settling for a new smart contract. Thanks for helping!